# Scaffolding and workflow for a Yesod sub-site?

Tags: cabal, yesod

The scaffolding for a normal (not sub-site) Yesod project creates a cabal file with a library section. This is necessary (as I understand) for the development infrastructure of Yesod.

Now the [gitit2](https://github.com/thkoch2001/gitit2) project is developed as a Yesod sub-site that comes with a very small Yesod application in the same project that uses the sub-site. The advantage is, that gitit2 can be used standalone or as a sub-site. Thus the library section in the cabal file is already in use for the sub-site.

I guess it would be best to split up the project in a project for the sub-site (libgitit2?) and another one for the small example application that uses the sub-site? That's unfortunate. I'd prefer to keep them in the same git repo and in the same hackage package.

Has anybody solved this problem? Are there good examples of Yesod sub-site projects to learn from? Maybe the Yesod scaffolding tool could add an option to create a sub-site project?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a common use case to create a sub-site project, and- to my knowledge- every such case is pretty custom. In other words, I can't imagine a good scaffolding approach for this. I'm not certain of what problems you're running into with single package vs multiple packages, so I don't think I can give advice on how to structure things.